# Share ownership of a Forge App with other team members

Tags: autodesk-forge

I've created a Forge app following the steps in the [sign-up flow](https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/start-now/signup), and it appears under the My Apps page https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps/ (under the personal section header)

**Is there a way to share this app with other members of my team?** Or to create a new app that is owned by multiple people? This would be important for us so we don't have a single point-of-contact for managing our Forge apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible today. You could create a shared Autodesk account, and create your Forge apps under that one.